# Persisting an environment variable through Ruby

Tags: windows, ruby, environment-variables, dos

I am trying to set my DOS environment variable in Ruby, and have it persist after the script exits. For example, if I want a ruby script `set_abc_env.rb` to set environment variable 'ABC' to 'blah', I expect to run the following:

```
C:> echo %ABC%
C:> set_abc_env.rb
C:> echo %ABC% blah
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can access environment variables via Ruby ENV object:

```
i = ENV['ABC']; # nil
ENV['ABC'] = '123';
i = ENV['ABC']; # '123'
```

Bad news is, as MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682009(VS.85).aspx), a process can never directly change the environment variables of another process that is not a child of that process. So when script exits, you lose all changes it did.

Good news is what Microsoft Windows stores environment variables in the registry and it's possible to [propagate](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011) environment variables to the system. This is a way to modify user environment variables:

```
require 'win32/registry.rb'

Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open('Environment', Win32::Registry::KEY_WRITE) do |reg|
  reg['ABC'] = '123'
end
```

The documentation also says you should log off and log back on or broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to make changes seen to applications. This is how broadcasting can be done in Ruby:

```
require 'Win32API'  

SendMessageTimeout = Win32API.new('user32', 'SendMessageTimeout', 'LLLPLLP', 'L') 
HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff
WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A
SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 2
result = 0
SendMessageTimeout.call(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 'Environment', SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, result)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for a solution for this and looking for a more of a hack that doesn't require logging in or out I came up with this solution for a similar problem :

**WORKAROUND:**

My work around is dependent on combination of ruby and a command line utility called [SETENV.EXE](http://barnyard.syr.edu/~vefatica/#SETENV) develped by Vincent Fatica. It's more than a decade old at this point but works fine in windows XP ( didn't test under Windows 7 yet). It works better than setx utility available from MS IMHO. At lest for deleting stuff. Make sure setenv is available from command line. Put it in some c:\tools and put c:\tools in your PATH.

Here  is a short example of a method using it:

```
def switch_ruby_env
  if RUBY_VERSION.match("1.8.7").nil?  
    `setenv -m CUSTOM_PATH " "`
  else
    `setenv -m CUSTOM_PATH -delete`
  end
end
```