# Use Ruby to permanently (ie, in the registry) set environment variables?

Tags: windows, ruby, registry, environment, win32ole

On Windows, how can I use Ruby to permanently set an environment variable?  I know I need to change the registry (through the win32ole module?) but I am a novice with regard to scripting the registry.

I understand that I can say `ENV['FOO'] = "c:\bar\baz"` to set the environment variable `FOO` for the session.  However, I am instead interested in setting environment variables globally and permanently.

I did find the patheditor gem, which works great for permanently altering the Windows `PATH`. But I want to set other environment variables, for example, `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190168/persisting-an-environment-variable-through-ruby) about this.  The basic gist is to set the variable in the registry via Win32::Registry (like runako said).  Then you can broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to make changes to the environment.  Of course you could logoff/logon in between then too, but not very usable.

Registry code:

```
require 'win32/registry.rb'

Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open('Environment', Win32::Registry::KEY_WRITE) do |reg|
  reg['ABC'] = '123'
end
```

WM_SETTINGCHANGE code:

```
require 'Win32API'  

    SendMessageTimeout = Win32API.new('user32', 'SendMessageTimeout', 'LLLPLLP', 'L') 
    HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 2
    result = 0
    SendMessageTimeout.call(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 'Environment', SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, result)
```

Thanks to Alexander Prokofyev for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190168/persisting-an-environment-variable-through-ruby/190437#190437).

Also see [a good discussion](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1envvars.htm) on Windows environment variables in general, including how to set them for the entire machine vs. just the current user ( in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SYSTEM\ CurrentControlSet\ Control\ Session Manager\ Environment)

Comment: I was able to read but not write or create keys, even on the HKEY_CURRENT_USER, I got Access is denied. The [attached pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TSEKeqyb) shows the errors since they're a bit long to put here. I was able to read the key though. Is there away to get around the permissions error, or use elevated permissions then step back down?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Win32::Registry :

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/Win32API/rdoc/classes/Win32/Registry.html

For reference, here's how I found it:

http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en-us&q=ruby+registry&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Anyhow, then you will want to do something like:

```
registry.open("HKEY_WINDOWS_GUNK/path/to/your/key", Win32::Registry::KEY_WRITE) do |reg|
   reg[regentry, Win32::Registry::REG_DWORD]=value
end
```

You might have to create a key first, if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I am pleased to see such a comprehensive set of answers!

It should also be noted that when creating/writing to entries under reserved/system keys (such as HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node on 64-bit Windows operating system) using constant flags such as Win32::Registry::KEY_WRITE and Win32::Registry::KEY_ALL_ACCESS will not exhibit desired behaviour unless the MRI (the Ruby interpreter) instance is started from an "Administrator" kernel context. Starting cmd.exe (Windows shell program) by right-clicking the executable and selecting "Run as Administrator" allows this.