# Is it possible to export environment property from ruby script?

Tags: ruby, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exporting an Environment Variable in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660571/exporting-an-environment-variable-in-ruby)

I need to set several environment properties from inside of ruby script.

Normally, in bash, I do the following:

```
$ export SOME_VAR=some_value
```

But in ruby, following (obviously) doesn't work:

```
irb(main):002:0> `export SOME_VAR=some_value`
(irb):2: command not found: export ASDF=1
=> ""
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This sound backwards to me. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JensTinfors i just used this in a ruby script which makes some shell commands, one of which expects a specific environment variable to be set.  If i was doing it in a bash script i would use `export`, but this won't work via a ruby shell command (backticks or system).  It seems to work fine using ENV like the answer say, so this was very valuable to me.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Its just that the environment variables you set will only be there for the current process. By backwards I mean that environment belongs to the shell, the ruby process is a subprocess of the shell, see what I mean? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/envvar.htm, you can just write:

```
ENV['SOME_VAR'] = 'some_value'
```

Comment: NB: this will set the environment variable for the current Ruby process as well as any sub-processes (eg: that you create with `system` or backticks).

Comment: @KyleBurton: Yes, absolutely. I'm assuming that's exactly what the OP wants, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ENV['SOME_VAR'] = 'some_value'.

You cannot make the effects of this persist in the environment executing the script, after the script is finished.

A trick that is being discussed in the comments to my answer, is to print valid shell code to the console, from your ruby script — this is *not* what you need, but it may be useful to know it could work that way too.

```
$ echo "puts 'export foo=bar'" > test.rb
$ echo $foo

$ source <(ruby test.rb)
$ echo $foo
bar
```

Comment: I really don't think `source ./my_script.rb` can be made to work. Think about it -- for what you're saying to be true, the Ruby script would have to run in the same process as the existing Bash shell, and then, when the Ruby script ended, the process would have to revert to being a Bash shell.

Comment: What the shebang should look like in this case?

Comment: You can 'source' the output of a program with bash like this: `source <(./my_script.rb)`

Comment: @KyleBurton: hm, tried just now, didn't work. I'm on mac osx.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that source thing was a long shot, my mistake.

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev the output from `my_script.rb` has to be valid bash syntax for it to work - what did you attempt to source?

Comment: @KyleBurton It really doesn't work under Mac, just tried it myself. Under Linux the exact same script works like a charm. Weird...

Comment: On Linux I have `GNU bash 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and on Mac I have `GNU bash, version 3.2.17(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin9.0)`. Maybe that's the culprit

Comment: @KyleBurton: i tried `source <(cat env.txt)` where env.txt contains valid `export` statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want this value to persist after script is finished, you can alter `ENV` directly.

```
ENV['SOME_VAR'] = 'some_value'
puts ENV['SOME_VAR']
# => some_value
```

If you do want persistence, then you probably (in addition to this) have to write this var to a `~/.bashrc` or similar file on your system.