# Rake not exporting PATH

Tags: ruby, path, environment-variables, rake

I would like a Rake task to export the path to my command line tool to $PATH, and so I have the following line in my Rakefile:

```
task :make_path do
  sh 'export PATH=$HOME/Desktop/folder:$PATH'
end
```

When putting that line `export PATH=$HOME/Desktop/folder:$PATH` into the terminal directly, the path is prepended to my $PATH variable. However if I run `rake make_path` nothing changes.  Why?

The following task correctly adds execute permission to my command line tool file:

```
task :chmod do
  sh 'chmod +x my_file'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `sh` from within a Rake task, it spawns a shell and executes the command.

The lifetime of environment variables, `PATH` being one of them, is until the shell exits.

So the `:make_path` task spawns a shell that exports this variable and then exits. Next time a shell is spawned, it has no knowledge of the modifications made to `PATH`.

For workarounds you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660571/exporting-an-environment-variable-in-ruby).