# How to pass shell script variables back to ruby?

Tags: ruby, shell, fastlane

I have a ruby script executing a shell script. How can I pass shell script data back to the ruby script.

```
      desc "Runs all the tests"
      lane :test do 

        sh "../somescript.sh"

        print variables_inside_my_script // i want to access my script data here.

      end
```

I'm able to do the reverse scenario using environment variables from ruby to shell script.

```
      desc "Runs all the tests"
      lane :test do 

        puts ENV["test"]

        sh "../somescript.sh" // access test using $test

      end
```

Thanks

Comment: Not possible. Subprocesses inherit a copy of the parent's environment; they can't affect the parent's environment. If you want to pass data from a shell script to the calling process, the easiest way to do it is through its output.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so clear what *variables_inside_my_script* is supposed to mean here, but as a rule operating systems do not allow one to "export" variables from a subshell to the parent, so rubyists often invoke the subcommand with backticks (or equivalent) so that the parent can read the output (stdout) of the subshell, e.g.

```
output = %x[ ls ]
```

There are alternative techniques that may be useful depending on what you really need -- see e.g.

1. [Exporting an Environment Variable in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660571/exporting-an-environment-variable-in-ruby)
2. http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html
3. http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If the shell script is under your control, have the script write the environment definitions in Ruby syntax to STDOUT. Within Ruby, you `eval` the output:

```
eval `scriptsettings.sh`
```

If your script produces other output, write the environment definitions to a temporary file and use the `load` command to read them.