# Returning value from fastlane fastfile

Tags: ruby, fastlane

My shell script would trigger a fastlane action (ruby) and I need return some value back to the shell script

One option being suggested everywhere is to set it as a env variable. 
But unable to print the value in shell script.

Fastlane action

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Description of what the lane does"
  lane :getData do
        ENV['FL_VALUE'] = "Test"
  end
end
```

Sample shell script

```
!/bin/sh
...
bundle exec fastlane getData
...
echo $FL_VALUE
```

other suggestions were to write the data into some file and read it from the shell script. But would prefer to use the env variable.

Comment: You can’t export an ENV variable to the parent shell from ruby but you can write a bash file that does it see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660571/exporting-an-environment-variable-in-ruby

Comment: Please open an issue at the fastlane repository with a feature request - being able to return data from a lane seems like a reasonable and very useful thing.

Comment: saw couple of postings requesting for that on their github repo, but no solution yet from then. But yes, will give a shot

Answer (score 1):

The project I am working on calls fastlane scripts from Groovy scripts. We have the lanes take an `output_file` option and write their results there. The Groovy scripts then read the results from the file. Cumbersome, but effective.

BTW: we also have an `error_file` option so errors can be written out similarly...