# is it possible to change the unix / macos environment variables from a ruby script

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a ruby script that can be run from a terminal session that could alter environment variables of the parent. I suspect this isn't possible as it create a new process but curious if any workaround. The motivation is we need to set a complex list of env variables to run apps locally and want to use a language that is available to everyone.

So, can Ruby do this? I'd rather not go the path of stopping a terminal session and restarting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting an Environment Variable in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660571/477037)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You Can't Modify the Environment of Parent Processes

Pragmatically, no application can change the environment for any process but itself, and exported values are only inherited by a child process *at the time the sub-process is spawned.* If you know enough about kernel programming to break that truism then you don't need to be asking the question. That means that, for your purposes, you can't export variables to a parent process from a sub-shell or spawned process, nor can you change the environment of a sub-process that has already been spawned.

### Helping Other Processes Modify Their Own Environments

So, you can't do what you want directly. Period.

However, if you design your programs in such a way that you can have them read from a file or file descriptor periodically or when signaled then you can edit the file from your spawned process with the expectation that something will occasionally import these values.

For example, if you have a Bash program like:

```bash
while true; do
    source new_env.sh
    # do something with new values
    sleep 5
done
```

then every 5 seconds the loop will import the *new_env.sh* file and any exports, commands, or variables defined there would become part of the current execution environment. You could also define a trap for SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 to read *new_env.sh* when it receives the signal and have it re-read the file then.

Ruby can do the same thing. You can define traps and loops that modify *ENV* for the current environment, which will then impact any sub-processes spawned from that point on. You can also serialize environment variables or other data and write them somewhere that can be read by another application. As a key distinction, this isn't allowing Bash or Ruby to directly modify another process' environment; it's simply a form of inter-process communication that could allow another process to modify itself.

### Caveats and Safety Concerns

Sourcing files at runtime is a huge security risk, and generally not recommended. You were given an answer that could work, but it's most probably solving the wrong problem. Most likely this is something you should look at from an architectural perspective rather than as an engineering work-around you need to find.

### An Example of Reading Configuration Files at Runtime

More generally, the correct way to modify values in a long-running program would be to read whitelisted values *from a trusted source* like a database or permission-controlled configuration file and then *sanitize the inputs* at runtime. For example, you might have your Ruby scripts do something like:

```rb
require "yaml"

# read file containing a serialized Ruby Hash
# such as {:foo=>1, :bar=>2, :baz=>3}
def config
  # read in your key/value store
  cfg = YAML.load_file "config.yml"

  # limit allowed values for Hash;
  # non-whitelisted values like :quux will
  # be ignored
  whitelist = %i[foo bar baz]

  @config.map do |key, value|
    # only process whitelisted keys, and sanitize
    # the values; in this case, that means coercing
    # them to Integer rather than accepting arbitrary
    # values
    cfg[key] = value.to_i if whitelist.keys.include? key
  end

  # re-export whatever you now have in @config, and then
  # return the Hash
  @config.map { ENV[_1] = _2 }
end
  
loop do
  config
  # spawn a process, send a signal, or use IPC
  # to communicate with something else
  sleep 5
end
```

This is meant as a trivial example, and not intended to be a bulletproof or ideal solution. However, it should give you a general idea of how to do this relatively safely, provided you have control over your configuration file, your whitelist, and that you treat the contents of said file as tainted and ensure that you sanitize and validate any values you read from it before using them.

It doesn't matter what language you're doing this in. You can use Ruby, Bash, Zsh, or whatever else you like. The general principle is the same, though: don't *source* the configuration file; *read* it and only process the lines and values you consider safe.