# How to add a new dword (32-bit) value in registry using ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, registry

I need to add a new dword (32-bit) value '1001' in the following registry path:

```
path = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\3\\"
```

After adding, the registry structure should look like this:
[image]

How can achieve the same using ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following lines solved the problem for me.

```
    Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.create(path) do |reg|
       reg.write('1001', Win32::Registry::REG_DWORD, 0)
    end
```

Here I'm setting the value 0 for newly created dword (32-bit) value '1001' in registry.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to modify user environment variables, have you tried this ?

```
require 'win32/registry.rb'

path = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\3\\"

Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open('Environment', Win32::Registry::KEY_WRITE) do |reg|
  reg[path] = '1001'
end
```

The documentation also says you should log off and log back on or broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to make changes seen to applications. This is how broadcasting can be done in Ruby:

```
require 'Win32API'  

SendMessageTimeout = Win32API.new('user32', 'SendMessageTimeout', 'LLLPLLP', 'L') 
HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff
WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A
SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 2
result = 0
SendMessageTimeout.call(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 'Environment', SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, result)
```

You may take a look at this [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190168/persisting-an-environment-variable-through-ruby/190437#190437) and this [usefull article](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1envvars.htm).

Comment: Executed the above lines. But it did not make any changes in registry.

Comment: @ ZazOufUmI - Even though the above lines did not answer my question exactly, it gave some hint me to find exact solution for the problem.